# H2 in-memory creating a server to access via Shell

Tags: java, h2, dropwizard

I'm using the `DataSourceFactory` of dropwizard and H2 to create an in-memory db for testing. Here is what I have

```
private static final String DBNAME = String.format("JDBITest-%d", System.currentTimeMillis());

protected final DataSourceFactory config = new DataSourceFactory();
{
    final String url = String.format("jdbc:h2:mem:%s;", DBNAME) +
                       "MODE=MySQL;" +
                       "TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=3;" +
                       "DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;" +
                       "IGNORECASE=TRUE";
    System.out.println("Creating in memory H2 using " + url);

    BootstrapLogging.bootstrap();
    config.setUrl(url);
    config.setUser("sa");
    config.setDriverClass("org.h2.Driver");
    config.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    Server server = Server.createTcpServer().start(); // (4)
    System.out.println("Server started and connection is open.");
    System.out.println("URL: jdbc:h2:" + server.getURL() + "/mem:" + DBNAME);
}
```

When this runs I see

```
Creating in memory H2 using jdbc:h2:mem:JDBITest-1541641621470;MODE=MySQL;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=3;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;IGNORECASE=TRUE
Server started and connection is open.
URL: jdbc:h2:tcp://0.0.17.56:9092/mem:JDBITest-1541641621470
```

Why is the TCP `0.0.17.56`? I cannot access this nor can I use the H2.jar to access the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several wrong things here.

**H2** has different connections modes. In your example you configure `DataSourceFactory` for **in memory** connection, but then in `@Before` method you create new instance of **H2** with **tcp based** connection. More about connection modes [here](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#connection_modes).

So now you have basically **2 instances of H2**, in memory and tcp and they are completely unrelated. So you probably need to have only 1 connection type configured for you tests.

If you want to connect to your **H2 db outside of JVM** (from browser for example) - then you need to have tcp-based connection.

To be able to connect to db from browser you also need to run console application. Which should be inside `h2.jar` with command like that `java -jar h2*.jar`. More about this [here](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html).

And finally, this peace of code should suitable for you (with in-memory connection):

```
private static final String DBNAME = String.format("JDBITest-%d", System.currentTimeMillis());
private ManagedDataSource dataSource;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    System.out.println("Server started and connection is open.");

    final String url = String.format("jdbc:h2:mem:%s;", DBNAME) +
            "MODE=MySQL;" +
            "TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=3;" +
            "DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;" +
            "IGNORECASE=TRUE";
    System.out.println("Creating in memory H2 using " + url);

    DataSourceFactory config = new DataSourceFactory();
    BootstrapLogging.bootstrap();
    config.setUrl(url);
    config.setUser("sa");
    config.setDriverClass("org.h2.Driver");
    config.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");

    dataSource = config.build(null, "test");
}

@Test
public void test() throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();

    connection.createStatement().executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE TEST (`id` INT)");
    connection.createStatement().executeUpdate("INSERT INTO TEST (`id`) VALUES (1)");
    ResultSet resultSet1 = connection.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE `id` = 1");
    resultSet1.next();
    resultSet1.getInt(1);

    System.out.println("Found ID: " + resultSet1.getInt(1));
}
```

Out:

```
Server started and connection is open.
Creating in memory H2 using jdbc:h2:mem:JDBITest-1541649996267;MODE=MySQL;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=3;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;IGNORECASE=TRUE
Found ID: 1
```